# How to add db context not in ConfigureServices method ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any posibility to add a db context in external class/method "on fly?" When I run the application, there is no any connection string, so I need to generate a db after typing some information(server, dbname, ect)

Comment: show some code in a [mcve] that better explains what you are trying to say. Right now it is unclear what you're asking. Read [ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use the factory pattern, i.e. creating a service that will be used to create new instances of your context.

Here is an example, it is not a final solution and you will need to adapt it to your needs but it should give you an idea of the technique:

```cs
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    DbContext CreateDbContext(string connectionString);
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    public DbContext CreateDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        return new DbContext(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Then in asp.net core, you can register the context factory and inject it in your controller:

```cs
 services.AddSingleton<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>();

 public class SomeController
 {
      private IDbContextFactory contextFactory;

      public SomeController(IDbContextFactory contextFactory)
      {
          this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
      }

      public IActionResult Index()
      {     
         using(var db = contextFactory.CreateDbContext("Your connection string"))    {
              //Get some data
         }
         return View();
     }
 }
```

Instead of creating a DbContext you could combine the factory pattern with the unit of work and / or repository patterns to better separate concerns and to make sure you always dispose the context, etc...

Comment: This answer got me to solve my own solution working with .net core 2.1 / signalr core and needed to setup a dbContextFactory as normal dbContext gets disposed inside a hub.

The only minor update needed here (for later versions) is now we call `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`, instead of `IDbContextFactory`.

More information can be found here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Use `new YourContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourContext>().Use...().Options)`