# Add Identity after ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to add Identity after the `ConfigureServices` method. It's because I have registered the `dbContext` outside the `ConfigureServices` method. So, now I have to configure Identity after configuring `dbContext` (Again, which I have done outside the `ConfigureServices`). What I have done for the `dbContext` is that I have created a factory and added it to the `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>();
```

Then I have used DI to inject it in my controller's constructor:

```
    private IDbContextFactory contextFactory;
    private AppDbContext context;

    public DbTestController(IDbContextFactory _contextFactory)
    {
        contextFactory = _contextFactory;
        context = contextFactory.Create(); //Create() returns an `AppDbContext`
    }
```

I am able to perfom CRUD operations on the database but, Identity won't work, it throws and exception:

`No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.XXX has been registered`

and that's because I am registering Identity in the `ConfigureServices`without setting up the `dbContext` first (Because it is set up after the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Is there a way to set up identity in the same manner as I have set up dbContext?

Edit: The `DbContextFactory` includes a `Create` method that returns an `AppDbContext`. It reads the user's choice for database provider from some config file, registers the provider accordingly and then returns the `AppDbContext`. Here is the code for the `Create` method:

```
public AppDbContext Create()
    {
        //Get this value from some configuration
        string providerType = _configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseProvider");

        //and the connection string for the database
        string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(providerType);

        var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

        //Add some if else blocks here to check which provider to use
        //and then call dbContextBuilder.UseABC(connectionString)
        if (providerType == "MSSQL")
            dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        else if (providerType == "SQLite")
            dbContextBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);


        //Create the context
        context = new AppDbContext(dbContextBuilder);

        return context;
    }
```

This method reads `providerType` & `connectionString` from `appsettings.json`. This is what the section looks like:

```
"DatabaseProvider": "MSSQL", //could be MySQL, SQLite etc etc
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MSSQL": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=XXX_db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"SQLite": "Data Source=XXX_db.db"
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'registered the dbContext outside the ConfigureServices method', nor why you would do so. Seems to me that there isn't a problem when you register both in ConfigureServices.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179400/9376397) post to create my dbContext outside the ConfigureServices method. Now that dbContext is not configured in the ConfigureServices, Identity also have to be configured outside ConfigureServices (along with dbContext). Yes, I could configure both of them in ConfigureServices but for this use case, I have to configure them somewhere other than ConfigureServices. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Can you show the code that throws the exception: No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.XXX has been registered

Comment: It's in my `AccountController` in the `Login` action:
`var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false);`. I have used DI to inject `_userManager` & `_signInManager` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the context and identity as usual in the `ConfigureServices`, applying the desired logic in the composition root at startup.

```
//Get this value from some configuration
string providerType = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseProvider");

//and the connection string for the database
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(providerType);

services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
    if (providerType == "MSSQL")
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    else if (providerType == "SQLite")
        options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
});

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

What you need to do is redesign the factory

```
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory {

    private readonly Func<AppDbContext> factory;

    public DbContextFactory(Func<AppDbContext> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public AppDbContext Create() {
        return factory();
    }
}
```

and register it accordingly with a factory delegate

```
services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>(sp => 
    new DbContextFactory(() => sp.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>()));
```

Comment: I can't register the context in `ConfigureServices` because I want to user to choose b/w different database providers and that selection happens in the `Create` method of my factory. It reads the user's choice from some config file, then registers the provider accordingly (MSSQL, SQLite etc) and returns the newly created `AppDbContext`.

Comment: Sorry, I have included the code for `Create` method in the question. As you can see, `providerType` gets its value from the `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this approach and it works perfectly fine but, I am trying to implement it the other way; just like I have taken the `AppDbContext` out of `ConfigureServices`. Is there any other way of implementing this?

Comment: I meant taking the Identity registration part outside the `ConfigureServices` method, just like I have taken the `DbContext` registration part outside the `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do it any other way? This answer is a good example of how to use this pattern and it works. Why choose a non-standard solution? It'll only make your code less maintanable.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yes I guess this solution makes more sense. I'll mark it as the answer.